# Mixed model development for repeated measures over 3 years

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, multiple-comparisons, biostatistics

I have longitudinal data for multiple plant varieties, where plants were measured for their *Performance* at 10 time points (*time*) each year for 3 years.

Each variety (*genotype*) serves as a distinct group with 3 individual plants (*replicate*). *Performance* is a measure of the living tissue remaining on the plant (0 - 100.00), and is observed to follow a nonlinear decrease over time. The values of *time* are equally spaced (10 weekly observations) and start in the same month each year.

In total:
50 varieties * 3 replicates per variety * 10 time points * 3 years = 4500 observations.

I am trying to fit a linear mixed model to compare each of the varieties over time, but am struggling to identify the correct model and how to incorporate both the *time* and *Year* effects. **Ultimately, I would like to be able to compare the varieties and be able to group them/ use compact letter display**.

My first attempt has been to model *genotype*, *Year*, and *time* as fixed effects, while specifying the *replicates* to be random effects to account for within-group variability.

```
mod1 <- lme(Performance ~ Genotype * Year * time,
            random = ~ 1 | replicate, data = df)
```

However, I know the data exhibits heteroscedasticity, with variation between *years*. To account for this, I added a variance model:

```
df$ID = df$Genotype:df$Rep

mod2 <- lme(Performance ~ Genotype * Year * time,
            random = ~ time | ID,
            weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | Year),
            data = df)
```

where the `random = ~ time | ID` component allows slopes to vary for `ID`.

Another model that uses an unstructured variance-covariance matrix for the *genotypes* within *Years*:

```
mod3 <- lme(Performance ~ Genotype * Year * time,
            random = list(Year = pdSymm(~ Genotype - 1),
                          Year = pdIdent(~ Rep - 1)),
            data = df)
```

1. Would this be an appropriate way to model the data and to handle *Year* and *time*?
2. Are any of these models more "correct" in terms of what they code for, rather than looking at AIC, BIC, or loglik values?
3. Would *post hoc* pairwise comparisons (`multcomp::glht()` or `emmeans::emmeans`) be appropriate to perform on one of these models, or would Fisher's LSD be another method to quickly check the means of each variety?
4. I've seen a paper where they only used the start and end time points, rather all measured data. Why would that be better than using all time points in the model?

Comment: 1. Could you tell us more about your response variable, "Performance"?
2. Are the plants measured at 10 equally spaced time points throughout each year?
3. Why is "Year" a predictor variable?

Comment: 1.  "Performance" is a measure of how much living mass is left on the plant (0 - 100.00) in response to drought stress. 2. Correct, the plants are measured at 10 equally spaced time points (weekly) throughout each year. 3. I listed "Year" as a predictor variable because I wanted to see if there is a temporal trend in the data. I've updated the OP for clarification.

Comment: Why is a "year effect" meaningful in your context? Don't you simply have measurements at 10x3=30 time points? And a trend in mean performance might occur over these time points?